# Ten children standing in line

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Ten children (five boys and five girls) are standing in line. Assume that all possible ways
in which they might line up are equally likely.

What is the probability that between any two girls there are no boys (i.e., the girls
stand together in an uninterrupted block)?

What is the probability that they alternate by gender in the line?

I'm trying to study for a midterm and an explanation of this would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

x x x x x o o o o o

o x x x x x o o o o

o o x x x x x o o o

o o o x x x x x o o

o o o o x x x x x o

o o o o o x x x x x

6 possibilities out of a total of $\binom{10}{5}=252$. So the prob that the girls are all together is $\frac{6}{252}$.

For your second question:

x o x o x o x o x o

o x o x o x o x o x

are the only possibilities. So the prob of alternating is $\frac{2}{252}.$